# Not able to get custom attribute data from Autodesk BIM360 for data management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

Not able to get custom attribute data from Autodesk BIM360 for data management API - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/

When I was trying to get all data available in a specific project with a specific folder, but I didn't get the custom attribute data in that. I also need custom attribute data for the file included in that folder. Whereas I am able to get only data and included values with missing custom attribute values. Also in the API custom attribute values are missing. please find it below.

```
data": [
    {
      "type": "folders",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.folder:hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Plans",
        "displayName": "Plans",
        "createTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:23.000Z",
        "createUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "createUserName": "John Doe",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2015-11-27T11:11:27.000Z",
        "lastModifiedTimeRollup": "2015-11-27T11:11:27.000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "BW9RM76WZBGL",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "John Doe",
        "path": "/dm-test-root/f0cb4ba0-7722-0133-9814-0eeb7bad1e3b",
        "objectCount": 4,
        "hidden": false,
        "extension": {
          "type": "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
          "version": "1.0",
          "schema": {
            "href": "/schema/v1/versions/folders%3Aautodesk.bim360%3AFolder-1.0"
          },
          "data": {
            "allowedTypes": [
              "folders",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:Document",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:TitleBlock"
            ],
            "visibleTypes": [
              "folders",
              "items:autodesk.bim360:Document"
            ],
            "namingStandardIds": []
          }
        }
```

I would like to save custom attributes with their values also.[Please find the image of the custom attribute with their values in the format of rows and colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUMqb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get custom attributes of the document in BIM360, you will need to use another endpoint (Version:Batch:Get). This blog tells more.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-attributes-apis-bim-360-document-are-now-public-beta

While please note, since March 23, 2021, in the newly created project, custom attributes definitions are created in project level (previously, in folder level), although you could still use the endpoint above to access the custom attributes, there is a gap that no endpoint yet to get definitions of project level. This blog tells more:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-attributes-projects-created-and-after-march-23-2021

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have understood your point. Do you have an idea when would be able to get the custom attribute data at project levels? Any development is going on by forge? @xiaodongLiang

Comment: yes, we are pushing engineer team to expose the related endpoint. Please make a note with this internal ticket number (ALEX-40828) for future reference. Thank you for your patience

Comment: That's would be great! Thank you. Could you please tell me how can I make use of the ticket number (ALEX-40828) for future reference? I really didn't get it. @Xiaodong Liang

Comment: you are welcome This ticket is logged within our internal. When you want to check its status, please log a case by emailing to forge.help AT autodesk.com . Our team can check status and reply you.

Comment: thank you so much! We have emailed Autodesk, but still no response from them whether an email has been reached or not?

Comment: I was on holiday. sorry for letting you wait.  The ticket number is for future checking as it has not any update right now. My colleague Michael has also replied you. Sorry for the bad news. I would suggest you check it again after a few months. We are also pushing engineer team to expose, while it will take time.